# gather and spread function in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have created a data frame using the below code:

```
stocks <- data.frame(time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
                   X = rnorm(50, 20, 1),
                    Y= rnorm(50, 20, 2),= rnorm(50, 20, 2),   
                   Z=rnorm(50,20,4))
)
```

I have applied gather function into the data frame:

```
res<-stocks%<%gather(company, value,-time)
```

while trying to spread the res I am getting the error:

```
spread(data=res, key=company , value = value)    

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows
```

Comment: You have a column without a name `=rnorm(50,20,2)`

Comment: and the code does not run as it contains a syntax error.

Comment: You need a sequence column i.e. `stocks%>%gather(company, value,-time) %>% group_by(company) %>% mutate(i = row_number()) %>% spread(company, value)`  It could be either `company` or `time` in the `group_by`.  As there is no expected output, it is not sure

Comment: @akrun I prefer using both `company` and `time`, as it indexes the observations for a particular company and time. It does not matter for the result, but the index makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

We need a sequence column to avoid the error `Duplicate identifiers...`

```
 stocks %>%
     gather(company, value,-time) %>%
     group_by(company) %>% 
     mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
     spread(company, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data:

```
stocks <- data.frame(time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
                     X    = rnorm(50, 20, 1),
                     Y    = rnorm(50, 20, 2),
                     Z    = rnorm(50, 20, 2))
```

I apply the `gather` like you and run `spread` on the result:

```
stocks %>% gather(company, value, -time) %>% spread(company, value)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 11, 21, 31, 41), (2, 12, 22,
```

When we look at the rows `c(1, 11, 21, etc)`:

```
         time company    value
1  2009-01-01       X 20.69259
11 2009-01-01       X 20.50856
21 2009-01-01       X 17.83796
```

we see that the `time` and `company` columns contain the same content, i.e. there are multiple observations for company `X` on that date. This leads to the error you see because `spread` cannot aggregate consistently.

You can solve this by adding an additional column that indexes the values per date and company:

```
res = stocks %>% gather(company, value, -time) %>% 
                 group_by(company, time) %>% 
                 mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
                 spread(company, value)
```

and to check we have `stocks` again:

```
all.equal(stocks %>% arrange(time), res %>% select(-i) %>% as.data.frame())
[1] TRUE
```